# How do you find the Thevenin equivalent for the circuit

Tags: thevenin

[image]

I open circuited the  current source and removed the power source and made it a short circuit. I cant seem to figure out how to find the equivalent resistance of the resulting circuit.

Comment: calculate series and parallel resistors

Comment: Now you already got some answers but, it would have been nice from you to actually show what you tried, just so people won't think you want them to solve your homeworks.

Answer (score 4):

If you redraw the schematic after applying the rules you mentioned, the resulting re-drawn schematic looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8a9ZX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It is now very easy to compute the resulting Thevenin resistance from this. And it will approximately match your solution answer.

For the voltage, you can do a Norton to Thevenin Conversion and find:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYAE5x.png)</sup>

This is very easily solved to find your solution's voltage. (And also your Thevenin resistance. In fact, you don't even need to bother with the first part I mentioned above. You can just use this last case to find both values.)

Answer (score 2):

Just redraw it if you can't do it in  your head, you'll see it's ((20||30)+30)||15||15 ohms = 42||7.5 = \$6\frac {4}{11}\Omega\$